# Login with google does not work on the apk release Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In debug mode the login works normally, I already configured the SHA1 and also added the internet permission, in debug mode it works normal, but when I generate the final apk it doesn't work (open for me to choose an account but after clicking it does nothing) ). Does the APP have to be on google play to work?

Comment: Hi, please explain what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Provide some screenshots, error trace, flutter version, Android version you're developing for etc.
All that information is needed to help you solving the problem. 
Good luck :)

Comment: Have you added a SHA1 for release or debug only?

Comment: I added it during debugging, but I figured it was the same key for both occasions.

As for "it doesn't work", what happens is that it opens the panel for the user to choose the account they want, but after selecting the account data, they are not received